# Throwing an exception in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My programming skills are not great, and I was hoping that someone would be able to guide me.

I am trying to integrate a predicted search function into a website, and i am using a JQuery plug-in to do so. I have got the search feature to work (the hardest part), and I just want to define a condition saying, if there are no products is stock displays “No match found” or whatever message. I just can’t get the condition to work, and I am running into syntax issues because I can even get the basic if else structure right.

Thank you for your time.

```
$().ready(function() 
{

    $("#name").hide();

    if ($("#course").autocomplete("get_course_list2.php", {
        width: 260,
    }));

    $("#course").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        $("#name").hide();
        $("#course_val").val(data[1]);
        result = "<strong> Product ID: </strong>" + data[1] + "<strong> Product Name: </strong>" + data[0]+ "<strong> </strong>";
        result += "<a href=\"http://restoftheurl?id="+data[1]+"\">Click Here to view the product</a>";
        $("#name").html(result);



    });

});
```

Comment: There is too much info missing in this question. But you should read this piece of doc: _"`$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)"_

Comment: Does your subject line mean you want to know how to throw an exception in JS or that your current code is throwing an exception and you want to prevent that?

Comment: @nnnnnn Basically I just want to throw another exception, I don’t want to prevent anything, everything is working the way it should do, I just want to define an additional else condition saying if the above condition is not true return “No match found”.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` holds response from the backend, then You can set a flag in `data` variable if no product was found; e.g. "NODATA". Then test `data` value before displaying products.

But the better way would be to communicating using JSON, so You can easily manipulate result.

**UPDATE**

OK. Let's go through this by simple steps. You're using jQuery plugin that You don't fully understand. This snippet does 2 things, first it request Your backend (get_course_list2.php on server) to fetch data, then inserts it to the DOM. The data that comes from backend is stored in variable data (because You chosen this name to describe 2nd argument of callback).

This is pseudocode of what I'm talking about (and how this would work):

**BACKEND, get_something.php**

```
$products = get_products_from_db();
if(count($products) > 0) {
    // lets print one products after a noter
    for(int i = 0; i < count($products); i++) {
        echo "<span>".$products[i]."</span>"
    }
} else {
    // nope, there is no products so lets tell frontend that there is nothing to display
    echo "NODATA";
}
```

**FRONTEND, display_something.js**

```
function(event, data, formatted) {
    if(data == "NODATA") {
        $(somewhereindom).html("No products");
    } else {
        $(somewhereindom).html(data); // data = "<span>Product 1</span><span>Prod 2</span>..."
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian,

You are assuming that I know how to apply what you just said to the snippet I attached. My programming skills are not that good my friend. An example justifying what you just said using JavaScript would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw this is the first time im using this website, so sorry if im not using it properly and i cant do the simple things like tag users, and display things in the correct format.

Comment: I've updated my answer, if You still don't catch please ask for concrete things.